# Facing database connection error

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to cakephp. I am facing this error:

> A Database connection using "Mysql" was missing or unable to connect.
>   The database server returned this error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Can you please suggest to me a solution?

Cakephp version is 2.x.

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post the complete error message including the full stacktrace (ideally copied from the logs where it it is available in a properly readable fashion)! Also show/describe the proper context, ie show the code that actually triggers the error, elaborate on your server environment (OS, DBMS, etc.)! Last but not least, please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This link will help you to connection of database in cakephp

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html